# Scheduled Event after some time Or Based on User Request

Tags: java

I want to have an operation(Task) to be Scheduled after some time OR Based on User Request. 
In my code I have something like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask();
timer.schedule(timerTask,time);//Time in milli seconds

if(UserRequestedtoCancel)
{
  // Do operatation 
  timerTask.cancel(); 
}
```

The problem is My task is still being executed after that time I specified, but only once. 
Should I also do timer.cancel(), or something else to avoid the task been executed?

Thanks

Comment: So you want the task to be executed only once either by the user or the scheduler???

Comment: Yes, I want it to be executed only once either by there User or the Scheduler .

Comment: So you can set a flag that will notify you that the task has been performed. Now both the blocks should check this flag whether the task has been performed or not.

Comment: But how can I cancel the task, that the scheduler needs to perform ?, based on a flag.

Comment: For now you can check the flag variable in the task itself, so you can skip the task.
Also the option you mentioned in your original question you can disable the timer when the user performs the task.

Comment: setting the timerTask = null after calling timerTask.cancel(), worked for me. I Had the task executed only once either by the user or the scheduler !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the timerTask = null after calling timerTask.cancel(), worked for me. I Had the task executed only once either by the user or the scheduler !